# Typedef of a struct with a member vector of pointers to objects of the same type returns scope error

Tags: c++, vector, struct, scope, typedef

Why is this invalid?

```
typedef struct _NODE_struct_
{
    int value;
    std::vector<node_t*> neighbors;
} node_t;
```

When this is valid:

```
struct node_t
{
    int value;
    std::vector<node_t*> neighbors;
};
```

The first gives `error: 'node_t' was not declared in this scope`. All my main function does is declare an object `n` of type `node_t`. It does not instantiate or manipulate.

Comment: You can't use a name before you have declared that name (there are some exceptions such as inside member functions). In the first example, `node_t` is declared after the `}`, so you may not use it inside the structure.

Comment: @dyp Thank you! Is  `typedef node_t struct...` valid then?

Comment: @LukeSmith no that isn't valid

Comment: If by "declare an object n of type node_t." you mean `node_t n;` then that is instantiation. (But it is nothing to do with your question, the first struct definition is invalid regardless of what comes after)

Comment: @LukeSmith `typedef` defines an alias for a type. It's basic form is `typedef TYPE NEW_NAME ;`, where `TYPE` can either be the name of an already declared type, or a type defined within the `typedef`. The latter, defining a type inside `typedef`, is what you're doing in your first example: `typedef struct { } my_alias ;` defines a type `struct { }` (with no name) and gives that type the alias `my_alias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to express what you're trying to say is to typedef a forward declaration.

```
typedef struct _NODE_struct_ node_t;

struct _NODE_struct_
{
    int value;
    std::vector<node_t*> neighbors;
};
```

But (especially since this is C++, not C) it would be better to not even use the typedef:

```
struct node_t;

struct node_t
{
    int value;
    std::vector<node_t*> neighbors;
};
```

(and even in C you could write `struct node_t*`)

but at this point, it becomes obvious that you don't even need the forward declaration. Also, all names that end in '_t' are reserved, so:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;
    std::vector<Node*> neighbors;
};
```

(ordinarily I would give the spiel about avoiding pointers in containers, but it looks like the nodes are borrowed peers, so it is correct)

Comment: Please do not call the first way "correct": first, the point about this being C++, not C already makes this bad, and second, `_NODE_struct_` is more reserved than `_t`, since it's reserved by the C++ standard, not by POSIX.

Comment: *"Also, all names that end in '_t' are reserved"* Huh? Who says that?

Answer (score 0):

The first code bit is trying to combine a definition with a typedef before it happens. If you are coming from a scripting or function context where you are trying to map an anon class, this does not work for C++. (I realize the comments answer the question, I thought I'd write this answer anyway just for reference.)